# Task<T> freezing UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

my block of code:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            var Users = GetUsers().Result;
            // proceed...
        }

private Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
{   
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<User>>();
    wbclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, e) => {
                if (e.Error == null)
                    tcs.SetResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(e.Result));
                else
                    tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
                };
    wbclient.DownloadStringAsync(someUri);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I want to get all the users before proceeding further. So I am calling the `GetUser` method in a dispatcher. I just want to wait until the `DownloadStringCompleted` event occurs and then return. But with the above code the UI freezes. Any help is appreciated.

**Note:**

I'm using `windows-phone 7`, which does not supports `async` `await`

Comment: No, no. NO. Dispatcher **forces** it to run in the UI thread.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance still UI freezing !!!

Comment: @AshokDamani: Yes, because you're using `Task<T>.Result`. Read the docs for that property.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  so than u mean i cant get it with Task<T>, is there any other alternative except async await ?

Comment: @AshokDamani: No, it means you shouldn't use `Task<T>.Result` in a UI thread when the task hasn't already completed.

Comment: but i already tried `ContinueWith` as @Darin Dimitrov suggested in his answer but not succeed !

Answer (score 3):

You should use a continuation and remove the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call and the `.Result` call in your main thread which is blocking:

```
GetUsers().ContinueWith(t => 
{
    List<User> users = t.Result;
    this.TextBlock1.Text = "Complete"; 
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Notice how I have used the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` call in the continuation to ensure that this continuation is marshaled on the main UI thread.

Comment: Note that this assumes this code is already executing on the UI thread. (Otherwise the current synchronization context won't be the right one.)

Comment: `GetUsers().ContinueWith(t => 
{
    List<User> users = t.Result;
    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`

well the UI not freezing. 
but the messageBox not showing too ?

Comment: Does the code execution enter the continuation? What happens when you put a breakpoint in it? Does the request succeed? Are you able to get the users?

Comment: Yes  the code execution enter the continuation, but `t.Result` still `null` !

Comment: so the issue was to wait the child execution until `DownloadStringCompleted` get occurs, which is not solved yet !

Comment: @AshokDamani In that case, what is the value `DeserializeObject()` returns? Is it `null`?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use async await on Windows Phone 7, you just have to install [this nuget packet](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to all of your projects in your solution. Works perfectly even when some projects are shared with Windows Phone 8 or some projects are portable class libraries. Very helpful.

So you should then be able to use: `var Users = await GetUsers();`

And by the way, you could always use HttpClient instead of WebClient : http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.1.10